# Scrollable element blocked by overlay div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a requirement to have an overlay div positioned (z-order) above a [pre] element that is scrollable. The problem is, I can no longer scroll within the pre element because the overlay is blocking it.

**Q: Is there any way to pass scroll events through divs so that they reach underlying elements?**

CSS:

```
.dropzone {

    pointer-events:none;
}

#myimage {

    float: left;
    border-width: 0px; 
    border-style: none; 
    background-color:none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}


#myoverlay {

    position: absolute;
    background-color:#139C8A;
    background-image: url('../images/drag-icon-white.png');
    background-size: 160px 66px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity:0.0;
    z-index:-1;
}

#myresponse {

    float: right;
    border-width: 0px; 
    border-style: none; 
    background-color:none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

 .mycode {

    text-align:left;
    color:#EFEFEF;
    background-color:#3C3C48;
    border-width: 0px; 
    border-style: none;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    position: relative;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="myoverlay">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="myimage">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="970" height="485"></canvas>
          </div> <!-- end col-md-4 -->
          <div id="myresponse">
            <pre id="mycode" class="mycode">
              <span style="color:#139C8A"><i>(Response will appear here)</i></span>
            </pre>
          </div>
          <div id="dropzone" class="dropzone-detect detect-droppable"></div>
        </div>
  </div><!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: You should provide a minimalistic sample to replicate your issue

Comment: Updated my answer, please try it. And: Your Code don't run here or in a fiddle. Please create a working example or we aren't able to help you.

Comment: @roNn23 tried your updated answer (which corrected my CSS error of using class instead of id) -- but now I cannot drag anything onto my dropzone. The pointer-events: none is preventing drag/drop events as well. Is there a more precise approach? Something like scroll-events: none?

Comment: Unfortunately not. They only way, I can think of, is that you catch the scroll event when the cursor is over the element and scroll the element in the background with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the CSS to the class `.dropzone`. But there is no dropzone-class, just an ID! Try the following CSS:

```
#dropzone { pointer-events:none; }
```

But please note, that [this isn't working in IE below version 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). For those browser, you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill).